# How can I divide one for loop to several loops and run them with threads to get shorter run time?

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops, visual-studio-2015

I am new to **C# multi-threading**. I have defined a simple **for loop** that when I press a button it starts counting from 0 to 10000 and using a **stopwatch** I captured the time period that it takes to finish this loop.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (double i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + ", ");

        }
        sw.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = sw.Elapsed;
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
        ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        MessageBox.Show(elapsedTime);
    }
```

> On my laptop it takes: 15':28''

On the other hand, I tried multi-threading in order to see whether I can shorten this time or not. What I did was:

1) Defining 5 functions (Func1,Func2, ...., Func5)

2) Inside each function I defined a for loop that counts one fifth of the main for loop:

Func1: 0 - 1000

Func2: 1000 - 2000

Func3: 2000 - 3000

Func4: 3000 - 4000

Func5: 4000 - 4000

3) Finally I defined **five different threads** and called each function in each of the threads.

Logically I expected to get the result in a shorter time, but the run time was the same as the time that I got without threads.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        Thread T1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Func1));
        T1.Start();

        Thread T2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Func2));
        T2.Start();

        Thread T3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Func3));
        T3.Start();

        Thread T4 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Func4));
        T4.Start();

        Thread T5 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Func5));
        T5.Start();

        T1.Join();
        T2.Join();
        T3.Join();
        T4.Join();
        T5.Join();
        sw.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = sw.Elapsed;
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
        ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        MessageBox.Show(elapsedTime);
    }
```

Can I shorten the run time using threads? If yes, how? and if no, what method should I use?

I tested this code to see the functionality of C# threads, It may seem useless but I will use it in an image processing app to shorten the run time of several for loops.

Please help.

Comment: What about the `Parallel` class? Also, note that using `Console.WriteLine` is slow and your code will run much faster without it.

Comment: The problem is Console.WriteLine !

Comment: A rule of thumb: if you needed to copy-paste some code 5 times, then you're doing something wrong. Don't write 5 methods, write just one that takes a parameter telling it where to start. (this does not change the fact that the problem lies within the `Console` class, which needs to be synchronized)

Comment: Generally if you're writing `new Thread` and this is not a .NET 2.0 application you're doing it completely wrong. There are very, very few scenarios where that's the right thing to do (and if you have to ask your scenario isn't one of them). Just use the [TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl)

Comment: @john Imagine that I have 4 different for loops that each of them does 3-4 lines of code like **adding a line of text to a text file.** Now how can I make them parallel? Note that each for loop can repeat from i=0 to i=1 million or a range similar to that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a restaurant. You only have one cook that cooks great but he's darn slow. You have one waiter that takes all the orders and hands them down to the cook. This is too slow and customers are starting to complain.

You have a bright idea (or not). You hire 100 waiters, that should make things much faster! Ok, now you've got orders getting to the cook a whole lot faster, but the food is still coming out at the same speed. How's that possible?

Change *cook* for `Console.WriteLine` and *waiters* for `Threads` and thats essentially what you are trying to do. You see how pointless it is?

Now, a whole different story would be if you have 10 *cooks* (processors) and only one *waiter* (thread). In that case, hiring 9 more waiters would make perfect sense.

Moral of the story? Use more threads and parallelize when you have processor bound tasks to perform and you have processors waiting around idly. Otherwise, there is normally better ways to do things than spinning up useless threads.

Comment: Nice story :-) You just explained it very well, thanks. But how can I fix this issue? My laptop is capable of doing multiple processes, but how can I assign more CPU resources to my project?

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi you are missing the point. Your laptop can have 100 processors, if the task at hand is not processor bound (the processor isn’t the bottleneck) then using more threads will be useless. I have no idea what task you are trying to solve so there is no way I can tell you how to solve it efficiently.

Comment: @Naser.Sadeghi `Console.WriteLine` is not processor bound. The console is orders and orders slower than what a processor could achieve. It’s limited by how fast it processes the messages it receives and it only has one messsage queue. If you put messages faster on the queue it will only get longer, not faster.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I just want to check the elements of a Circular List in two directions (**Clockwise and counter clockwise**). I must check any sequence of elements(I mean starting from the length 1 to the length:  `MyList.Count();`). I have used a **for loop** for clockwise and another for counter clockwise. All I want is making these two loops work together and get the result faster. Inside each loops operations like writing a line to a text file are happening.